# 90-degree rotation using only reflections?

Tags: algorithm, reflection, graphics, rotation, mirroring

Is there an algorithm for rotating a (presumably square) image 90 degrees (either cw or ccw) with the only operation available being mirroring (either vertical, horizontal or both) an arbitrary rectangular section of the image? The algorithm should be optimal in the number of operations done.

Comment: What can you do with two such mirror operations? What with four? One?

Comment: Two mirror operations (one horizontal and one vertical) rotates the image 180 degrees. However, no luck for 90 degrees. I think that even if such a solution exists, it must almost certainly iterate through thin segments of the image, repositioning pixels multiple times --> slooow.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. If you have a rectangle that is 2 units tall and 1 unit wide, it will be the same way up after a horizontal or vertical reflection.

You can rotate a rectangle through 90 degrees using 2 reflections, but the mirror line for one of them should be diagonal.

```
AB
DC
```

Step 1: Reflect in diagonal line through `A`:

```
AD
BC
```

Step 2: Reflect vertically:

```
DA
CB
```

The original rectangle has been rotated 90 degrees clockwise.

Comment: "Padding" the image to be a perfect square, and using the newly added (really nonexistent) part in a reflection (then cutting it off when finished) is counted as a valid solution. Does this open any possibilities for a solution?

Comment: No because if you are only ever reflecting horizontally or vertically, there's no way of getting an image on its side.